# Safe import of modules from liquid-base fails

Tags: haskell, import

I've updated dependencies for a library. Instead of using Prelude from base (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html) I now use Prelude from liquid-base (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/liquid-base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html). On these Hackage pages I can see that the old module had *Trustworthy* status wrt Safe Haskell while the new one has *None*. The change caused Safe Haskell errors like this one:

```
.../eccrypto/src/Crypto/Fi.hs:40:1: error:
    Prelude: Can't be safely imported! The module itself isn't safe.
   |
40 | import safe Prelude as P 
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

1. Why does the module has status *None*? Is it a bug in safety inference? The definition of the module is basically just imports of other, *Safe* or *Trustworthy*, modules.
2. What's the best way to fix the compile error? Adding this to my cabal file didn't help:

```
ghc-options: -trust liquid-base
```

3. How much do I lose when I use `import` instead of `safe import`? This fixes the issue.